# VB.NET concatenating strings adds unwanted space

Tags: vb.net

I'm completely mystified why this is happening. I'm writing a small app to prefix image files with the date-taken property. However when I append the .jpg extension it adds a space between the filename and the extension. For example "2017-11-07_13:04:01 .jpg".

```
 Private Function ProcessFile(ByVal path As String) As String
    Const DATE_TAKEN As Integer = &H9003
    Dim img As Image = Image.FromFile(path)
    Dim dateTaken As String
    Dim pitem As PropertyItem
    If img.PropertyIdList.Contains(DATE_TAKEN) Then

        pitem = img.GetPropertyItem(DATE_TAKEN)
        dateTaken = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(pitem.Value, 0, pitem.Value.Length).ToString

        dateTaken = Trim(Replace(Replace(dateTaken, ":", "-"), " ", "_"))
        dateTaken = Replace(dateTaken & ".jpg", " ", "")
    Else
        dateTaken = "Not available"
    End If
    img.Dispose()
    pitem = Nothing
    Return dateTaken
End Function
```

As you can see I've tried to replace the space by trimming and replacing but nothing works.

Comment: Well, it's obviously not a space character, since the replace isn't removing it.  So, get that character from the string and see what it's value actually is.  Without knowing anything about the format of that date-taken field, my initial guess would be that it's not actually a UTF-8 string.  Either that or it's null terminated and it's actually a null character at the end rather than a space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you get the date from the file, it includes a `VbNullChar"

All you need to do is add in a line of code to trim that out ..

```
Private Function ProcessFile(ByVal path As String) As String
    Const DATE_TAKEN As Integer = &H9003
    Dim img As Image = Image.FromFile(path)
    Dim dateTaken As String
    Dim pitem As PropertyItem
    If img.PropertyIdList.Contains(DATE_TAKEN) Then
        pitem = img.GetPropertyItem(DATE_TAKEN)
        dateTaken = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(pitem.Value, 0, pitem.Value.Length).ToString
        dateTaken = dateTaken.Trim(vbNullChar)
        dateTaken = Trim(Replace(Replace(dateTaken, ":", "-"), " ", "_"))
        dateTaken = Replace(dateTaken & ".jpg", " ", "")
    Else
        dateTaken = "Not available"
    End If
    img.Dispose()
    pitem = Nothing
    Return dateTaken
End Function
```